# VueJS | How to make your background image fill all the page?

Tags: vue.js, background, background-image

I want the background image to fill all the page but unfortunately just fill half space.

Here my code :

```
<template>
  
  <div class="backgroundImage" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + require('../../assets/bkg.jpg') + ')'}">
          
    <img class="logo-img" src="../../assets/logo.png" alt="Logo FunkTheTown" title="FunkTheTown" />
  
 </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {

}

</script>

<style scoped>

.backgroundImage{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

Tks for the help
ps: i've tried cover in background-size css property same result.

Comment: This is a **component**! Do you import it in another component?

Comment: yes, directly into the App.vue File. This is the only component for the moment.

Comment: In the App.vue file, do you have a HTML template also? Maybe your not in the good component to make it fullscreen. At least you could use css `position:fixed;` with `left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;`

Comment: Your advise on css worked, very thanks a lot for your help.